# What is a .exe~ extension?

Tags: go, bazaar

I noticed that `go build` is now creating a `.exe` and a `.exe~`

I've googled and found nothing, this only started happening after one of the bazaar libraries was used as a dependency to a package I am using.

Do I need the `.exe~` for anything? Can I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience with Go on Windows, the `go build` command will create an `.exe~` shadow file because of:

1. You previously build the runtime and created an .exe.
2. You already started/executed the binary.
3. That previous execution *is still running* or some other stupid file lock by windows has occurred.
4. You attempt to `go build` again, while the previous binary was still in use.

What happens under the hood is the `go build` will rename the existing executed .exe to .exe~ while it is in use, and will place the new binary at .exe for the next execution.

I have always been fascinated by how it does that to files in use, when 20+ years of all other Windows apps returns the dreaded "File In Use" error.

My best guess is that when you execute a go binary, the execution does not place a file lock on the file.  So the next build can simply rename the in use one.

During my tests (2014) that new .exe was the latest version and the .exe~ was the previous version that was running.

I did a lot of testing around this as my use case purposely replaced the existing binary upon recompiling.